# select2 : launch function when input change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

I use a select2 tag to choose a selection of users from the database.
The problem is that the users database is huge, I don't want to have a list of a thousand possibilities while using select2.

I want the possibilites to change only when I type in the input field. Like a ng-change, but ng-change only works when you add or remove a choice in your model.

Ex : I would have an empty list at beginning, and if I type "Mike" I would have all users who are called "Mike"

```
<select2 multiple placeholder="Choose users" ng-model="usersSelection" s2-options="user.id as user.name for user in users"></select2>
```

Do you know how I could do that ? select2 code is huge, I'm just searching for a simple solution, like a watch function.

Thanks, and sorry for my english.

Comment: What about using a jQuery listener, like https://api.jquery.com/keypress/?

Comment: It doesn't work, I think it's because of the select2 tag, instead of a simple input tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `angularjs`, but can't you use the property `minimumInputLength` when initializing the `select2` box?

```
$("#element").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ...
});
```

Comment: Select2 uses `maximumSelectionLength: 3`, inputLength would only require the minimum amount of input characters.

Comment: But this is a different scenario, isn't it? The documentation says, `maximumSelectionLength` limits the number of selected items. `minimumInputLength` is a setting, when to start the query as I understand.